# Will the app only works in devices listed in the Play Console device catalog?

Tags: android, google-play-console, chromebook

I want to purchase a Chromebook device for the development and testing of my Android app. But none of the supported devices in the [Google Play Console device catalog](https://play.google.com/console/about/devicecatalog/) aren't available in my region.

What happens if I purchase a device that is not listed as a supported device? Will it helpful for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a Chromebook that wasn't listed in [Google Play Console device catalog](https://play.google.com/console/about/devicecatalog/) and my app works fine on it.

Comment: Hi how does you install it? Through Android Studio or from Google Play Store?